# Why weighted sum is called Archimedean sum?

Tags: optimization, terminology

I study goal programming. And one of the way to solve multi-objective problem is to reduce several objectives to the weighted sum
$$
a_1f_1(x) + a_2 f_2(x) + \dots + a_n f_n(x) \to \min
$$
where $a_i \geq 0$. This sum is called Archimedean sum in weighted goal programming. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about the physical intuition regarding [leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever). The higher weight something has the more influence it has.

Archimedes' work *On the Equilibrium of Planes* (Greek: Περὶ ἐπιπέδων ἱσορροπιῶν) was one of the early works formalizing a mathematical treatment of an ideal lever, although people in various parts of the world "knew" about this before the publication of that book.